# Copying files to a project subdirectory in a SCons hierarchical build

Tags: scons

Consider this SCons project:

```
myproject/
  resource/
  objects/
     SConscript
     foo
     bar
  src/
     SConscript
     ...
  SConstruct
```

In `objects/SConscript`, I have some rules to make intermediate files. To simplify the example, though, let's reduce it to a raw copy. I'd like copies of `foo` and `bar` to wind up in `myproject/resource` after the build.

`objects/SConscript` looks like:

```
Import('env')
data_out = '#/resource'
# ...
env.Install(data_out, 'foo')
env.Install(data_out, 'bar')
```

However, when I run `scons objects` from the project root, some of the intermediate rules are run, but `myproject/resource/` does not contain the copied files.

(I don't know if this is relevant, but the `objects` sub-build uses a variant_dir).

Why is this? What is the idiomatic way to get those files into the `resource` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by running SCons as:
`scons objects`

You are only asking SCons to build targets under that directory.
You're install/copied files are in `#/resource`, so they are not processed.

You can resolve this by running SCons as:
`scons objects resource`

Or if you always want to do the copy into `#/resource` you can add the following to your SConscript

```
Import('env')
data_out = '#/resource'
# ...
env.Install(data_out, 'foo')
env.Install(data_out, 'bar')
Default('#/resource') # This line added
```

Or you can add an `Alias()` in your SConstruct

```
Alias('object_and_resource',['#/object','#/resource'])
```

Or you can gather only the items installed from objects into resources into an Alias() as well.

Or you could specify the targets for however you build `foo` to be in the `#/resource` dir and then just `scons resource` would do it too.

Really depends exactly what you want to happen.

Note that this is mostly covered in the [FAQ](https://scons.org/faq.html#How_do_I_install_files.3F_The_Install.28.29_method_doesn.27t_do_anything._In_general.2C_how_do_I_build_anything_outside_my_current_directory.3F)

Comment: Running `scons resource` or `scons` from the root dir did work, thank you. The `Default(...)` command didn't work as described, though— even with the Default command included, `scons objects` doesn't install the files.

Comment: Default() only applies when you don't specify a target to build. It doesn't automatically append to any command line specified targets.